# C#/XNA Giant Memory Leak

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, xna

this is my first post here.
I'm making a game in Visual Studio 2010 using XNA, and i've hit a giant memory leak. My game starts out using 17k ram and then after ten minutes it's upto 65k. I ran some memory profilers, and they all say that new instances of the String object are being created, but they aren't live. The amount of live instances of String hasn't changed at all. It's also creating instances of Char[] (which i'd expect from it), Object[], and StringBuilder. My game is pretty new but there's too much code to post here. I have no idea how to get rid of instances that aren't live, please help!

Comment: I'm not sure I would consider 65k a "giant memory leak".  You could almost fit that on a personal computer from 30 years ago.  If it was blowing up to 650MB I might be a little worried.

Comment: I'm guessing you must mean up to 65,000K, as I don't think you can even get down to a 17K hosted process size anymore.  Even then, 65M is not all that big by modern standards.

Comment: Okay, we'll if that's okay then illjust let it slide. It does reset occasionally. Thanks so much! And yes I meant 65,000k lol

Answer (score 5):

You haven't posted enough information to provide you with more than an educated guess. Here is my educated guess:

If you are doing things like this in your Draw method:

```
spriteBatch.DrawString(font, "Score: " + score, location, Color.Black);
spriteBatch.DrawString(font, "Something else: " + foo, overHere, Color.Black);
spriteBatch.DrawString(font, "And also: " + bar, overThere, Color.Black);
```

Then each of those calls will be creating new `string` and `StringBuilder` objects behind your back each time they run. Because they are in your `Draw` method, each is probably running 60 times per second. That is a lot of temporary objects being allocated!

To verify that this is the case - use the CLR Profiler. It sounds like you have already done this.

While this isn't really a "leak" - the Garbage Collector will eventually clean them up - this allocation pattern is undesirable in a game. See [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/shawnhar/archive/2007/07/02/twin-paths-to-garbage-collector-nirvana.aspx) about two methods for dealing with garbage collection in a game. Method 1 is usually easier and provides better results - so I am discussing it here.

It is worth mentioning at this point that the GC on the PC is fast enough that allocations like this **don't really matter**. The GC will clean up tiny objects (like your temporary strings) with very little overhead.

On the Xbox 360, on the other hand, even producing tiny amounts of garbage like this regularly can cause some serious performance issues. (I'm not sure about WP7, but I would personally treat it like the Xbox -- with care!)

**How do we fix this?**

The answer is simple: `DrawString` will accept an instance of `StringBuilder` in place of `string`. Create one instance of `StringBuilder` and then reuse it each time you need to put together a custom string.

Note that converting a number or other object to a string, implicitly or by its `ToString()` method will also cause allocations. So you might have to write your own custom code to append to `StringBuilder` without causing allocations.

Here is one I use, in the form of an extension method, for appending integers to a string without allocating:

```
public static class StringBuilderExtensions
{
    // 11 characters will fit -4294967296
    static char[] numberBuffer = new char[11];

    /// <summary>Append an integer without generating any garbage.</summary>
    public static StringBuilder AppendNumber(this StringBuilder sb, Int32 number)
    {
        bool negative = (number < 0);
        if(negative)
            number = -number;

        int i = numberBuffer.Length;
        do
        {
            numberBuffer[--i] = (char)('0' + (number % 10));
            number /= 10;
        }
        while(number > 0);

        if(negative)
            numberBuffer[--i] = '-';

        sb.Append(numberBuffer, i, numberBuffer.Length - i);

        return sb;
    }
}
```

Comment: You technically don't need numberBuffer; just append 1 char at a time (faster due to reduce cache hits). If you are concerned about resizing, use sb.EnsureCapacity(sb.Length + 16) to prevent it (16 to retain cache line alignment).

Comment: Oh wow, this makes so much sense. I'll try this as soon as I can, thanks so much!

Comment: @GGulati While you are right that calling `Append` on characters performs slightly better than building the string in a buffer and dropping it into place, **note that the algorithm is building the string right-to-left**. I'll leave figuring out a left-to-right algorithm as an exercise ;) Furthermore: no point worrying about `EnsureCapacity`. The whole point here is to reuse a buffer. So getting the capacity up will happen once. And the CPU time is such a tiny difference. This is a specific GC optimisation. Bad form to layer unnecessary extra optimisations on top.

Answer (score 2):

There are no memory leaks in C# (or well, they're *very* difficult to get). What you are experiencing is normal. The garbage collector doesn't "feel" like it needs to collect memory, so it does not. Whenever memory runs short, garbage collection will occur. If you're *absolutely* certain that you aren't keeping unneeded references to your `string`s, then everything's fine.

If you want to force a GC cycle use `GC.Collect()`.

Comment: Using `GC.Collect` in a game is not a good idea, it's better to use object pooling inside the game loop and just avoid dynamic allocations.

Comment: Some part of XNA is not managed code, so the GC will not work. like this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3364481/outofmemory-exception-when-drawing-cube